# Dialog with custom dialog builder

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to create custom dialog with custom builder pattern? I have already tried extending DialogFragment and I have created custom Builder, but I don't understand how to attach builder to dialog, maybe someone has an example?

Comment: if  you want to create custom dialog box , go through this.. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/13341560/6559031

Answer (score 0):

> Just **simple extend the custom class with Alert Dialog** ! and in its on
>   Create you can SETCONTENTVIEW() your design

**like this**

```
public class FoodDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public FoodDialog(Context context){
        super(context);

    }

    @override
    public onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.setTitle("Confirm?");
        setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_dialog_layout);
  }
```

**NOTE! ABOVE ONE IS FOR ALERT DIALOGE BUT!**

> SAME CAN BE DONE BY extending the CUSTOM CLASS WITH Dialog(base class)
>   and can do any kind of designing on it!

Comment: But how I could add custom Builder to it? Because I need to implement progressbar and cancel button inside dialog, and I need to pass progress value through builder.